# eapply usage to user defined function

Tags: r, function, quantmod

I want to use user defined function via eapply to an environment which stores tickers, but not sure what I am doing wrong...

```
    library(quantmod)

    slideapply <- function(x, n, FUN=sd) {

    v <- c(rep(NA, length(x)))

    for (i in n:length(x) ) {

     v[i] <- FUN(x[(i-n+1):i])

    }


    return(v)

    }


    augenSpike <- function(x, n=20) {

    prchg <- c(NA, diff(x))

    lgchg <- c(NA, diff(log(x)))

    stdevlgchg <- slideapply(lgchg, n, sd)

    stdpr <- x * stdevlgchg

    #shuffle things up one

    stdpr <- c(NA, stdpr[-length(stdpr)])

    spike <- prchg / stdpr

    return(spike)

    }


    myenv <- new.env()
    # environment used to store tickers
    tickers <- c("PBR", "AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG")
    getSymbols(tickers, env= myenv)

# the above works fine, but below is the problem    

    asp <- eapply(augenSpike(as.vector(Cl(myenv), FUN=augenSpike))
    sp$spike <- asp

# I get the message: 
## unexpected symbol in:
## "asp <- eapply(augenSpike(as.vector(Cl(myenv), FUN=augenSpike))
## sp"
```

Comment: You're missing a right paren. `eapply(augenSpike(as.vector(Cl(myenv))), FUN = augenSpike)`

Comment: I tried that way but I get Error in Cl(myenv) : 
  subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Close"

Comment: What about `eapply(myenv, function(x) augenSpike(as.vector(Cl(x))) )`? I believe that is what you are trying to do. If not, please clarify the question

Comment: You are the man!  Thank you, this last one provided exactly what I was looking for...